# "Deprecation Notice" error in phpmyadmin with 16.04

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

I am getting errors when I launch phpmyadmin in 16.04:

```
Deprecation Notice in ./../php/php-gettext/streams.php#48

Backtrace

./../php/php-gettext/gettext.inc#41: require()
./libraries/select_lang.lib.php#477: require_once(./../php/php-gettext/gettext.inc)
./libraries/common.inc.php#569: require(./libraries/select_lang.lib.php)
./index.php#12: require_once(./libraries/common.inc.php)
```

It continues with these as well with the same backtrace as above:

```
Deprecation Notice in ./../php/php-gettext/streams.php#84
Deprecation Notice in ./../php/php-gettext/streams.php#145
Deprecation Notice in ./../php/php-gettext/gettext.php#36
```

I have updated and verified that I am on the latest gettext and mbstring.  Any thoughts on resolving?

Comment: On [this tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-secure-phpmyadmin-on-ubuntu-16-04) it says that you have to enable `mcrypt` and `mbstring` php modules and restart apache. Did you do that?

Comment: yes I updated mcrypt and mbstring and have restarted apache.

Comment: I will recommend [download the package directly ](https://www.phpmyadmin.net/downloads/) that fits your php/mysql versions, to troubleshot.

Answer (score 29):

This depends whether you are adventurous enough. If you understand the error, it means your PHP has some old class constructors.

**OLD Php Class Constructor**

```
Class myclassname {

    function myclassname() {
      //This is a constructor
    }
```

**New Php Class Constructor**

```
Class myclassname {
    function __construct() {
      //this is the new constructor using __construct instead of the same function name as class name.
}
```

So what I did was to go into `/usr/share/php/php-gettext/stream.php` and `/usr/share/php/php-gettext/gettext.php` (or whatever file stated in your error), go to the file and change `function myclassname()` to `function __construct`.

The function `myclassname` should be identical to the CLASS `myclassname` declaration.

You should see about 4 errors if you are on ubuntu 16.04 with latest gettext. I just change that and it's not harmful to your system. It's a outdated programming syntax and if you upgrade in the future you wouldn't face any problem too. I will say it's a safe edit.

It's not really a major change or anything, just syntax updating. If you install from apt-get package you really have no other choice unless you compile yourself.

```
sudo nano /usr/share/php/php-gettext/streams.php
```

**Line 48 StringReader Error.**

Go to Line 52 and change

```
function StringReader ($str='') {
```

TO

```
function __construct($str='') {
```

**Line 84 FileReader Error**

Go to Line 90 and change

```
function FileReader($filename) {
```

to

```
function __construct($filename) {
```

**Line 145 CacheFileReader error**

Go to Line 146 and change

```
function CachedFileReader($filename) {
```

to

```
function __construct($filename) {
```

Using `sudo nano /usr/share/php/php-gettext/gettext.php`.

**Line 36 `gettext_reader {` error**

I think you get the gist now, go to line 101 and change

```
function gettext_reader($Reader, $enable_cache = true) {
```

To

```
function __construct($Reader, $enable_cache = true) {
```

Comment: one should see : `sudo nano /usr/share/php/php-gettext/gettext.php` and `sudo nano /usr/share/php/php-gettext/streams.php`

Comment: the packaged files are from 20101225. So even though keeping backups is just what you do - always - you should be safe from a package update unfixing your fix, any updates should contain that fix by themselves!

Answer (score 8):

Since I don't have enough reputation yet to comment on **Someone Special**'s great answer, I'll just reply instead.

Here are the one-line commands that perform the suggested edits:

```
sed -ri.bak 's:function StringReader.*:function __construct($str=\x27\x27) {:' /usr/share/php/php-gettext/streams.php
sed -ri 's:function FileReader.*:function __construct($filename) {:' /usr/share/php/php-gettext/streams.php
sed -ri 's:function CachedFileReader.*:function __construct($filename) {:' /usr/share/php/php-gettext/streams.php
sed -ri.bak 's:function gettext_reader.*:function __construct($Reader, $enable_cache = true) {:' /usr/share/php/php-gettext/gettext.php
```

Comment: saved me a bit of time there... thanks man :-)

Answer (score 5):

You can use another PPA for phpmyadmin.Here it is [PPA Link](https://launchpad.net/~nijel/+archive/ubuntu/phpmyadmin)

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nijel/phpmyadmin
sudo apt update
sudo apt install phpmyadmin
```

As it is only a temporary solution or not a optimal one, till the package of phpmyadmin in ubuntu repos are rebuild.

Comment: This helped me though

Comment: Be careful, this ppa hasn't received any update for more than a year.

Answer (score 0):

This deprecation notice" message on login page of phpMyAdmin issue is easily solved by editing the php.ini file at `/etc/php/7.0/apache2/php.ini`

Change error_reporting value to:

```
error_reporting = ~E_DEPRECATED & E_ALL
```

By default it is on comment position, so uncomment it and change it.

Then restart Apache:

```
sudo systemctl restart apache2
```