# Set phpmyadmin to never ask about deprecation warnings on ubuntu

Tags: phpmyadmin

I am getting annoyed by error reports about deprecated in phpmyadmin on php8

According to https://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/config.html

*All configurable data is placed in config.inc.php in phpMyAdmin’s toplevel directory.*

I have tried to create the file `/usr/share/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php` with this

```
<?php
$cfg['SendErrorReports'] = 'never';
```

But it doesn't seem to be loaded

The default setting is in:

`/usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries/config.default.php`

If I change it in there it works but I guess the file will be overwritten with next upgrade.

Is there a better or correct way to set the config?

Comment: This could help: https://askubuntu.com/questions/796135/deprecation-notice-error-in-phpmyadmin-with-16-04

Comment: This could also turn off deprecation warnings: `error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_DEPRECATED);` I think you need to add to your PHP code. https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/php/php+disable+deprecation+warnings

Comment: @Jeff i don't want to turn of for other projects which i develop

Comment: That makes sense. In that case, don't do what I suggest...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The settings can be set in the phpmyadmin gui at http://localhost/phpmyadmin/prefs_forms.php?form=Features